# using enum as parameter in a sub

Tags: c#, enums

I've tried searching and have not found an answer.  I've done a lot of vb.net programming and am starting to do some c#.  In vb.net I can do

```
 Public Enum LoginLogActivity
        LoginSuccessful = 1
        LoginFailed_Email = 2
 End Enum
    Shared Sub LoginLog(pActivity As LoginLogActivity, mEmail As String, Optional mSessionGUID As String = "", Optional pMisc As String = "")
end sub
```

when I use the LoginLog sub elsewhere in code when I type LoginLog( the different values of the enum show up for me to select (Visual Studio 2013).

When I try to create something similar in C# I don't get the enum values to show up.  I can type out the FadeDivType.List and it will accept that, but i'd like for intelliscene to show me the values when I am to fill in that parameter.

```
public enum FadeDivType
    {
        List,
        String
    }
public static void _FadeDiv(FadeDivType pFadeDivType, string pFadeDivText){}
```

would appreciate hearing what i'm not doing correctly.
Thanks
Shannon

******************Here is a shot at what it is doing.

[image]

Hopefully you can see where the cursor is.  So when I type FadeDiv(  in vb.net the enum would show u with a list I could select from.  What i'm experiencing is just a blinking cursor that I have to type in all the information.  The line above is what I had typed in.  Once it's typed in the code works correctly.. just want that intellisence.

I don't see any error in the error list other than the _FadDiv need arguments

Comment: Intellisense does do that. Perhaps show all relevant compiler warnings and errors, and a screenshot of what is happening on your screen.

Comment: May have found the issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588340/visual-studio-2013-intellisense-does-not-put-enum-type-in-a-place-of-a-parameter   looks like it could be a bug that will be fixed at some point.  Verified that this is the issue.